# Did Dr. Doom eventually find out that Thanos was watching over him?

Tags: marvel, thanos, dr-doom

My friend and I were having a debate on Dr. Doom vs Thanos.  He told me that Thanos has Dr. Doom under constant watch because he considers him a threat. I have seen the scans. My question is did Dr. Doom ever find out he was being watched by the mad Titan? And if so, what happened?

Comment: "I have seen the scans." - Could you clarify which comic you're referring to?

Comment: Hey Paul I am not sure what comic it is, but the scan I saw had Thanos explaining on why he watches Doom.

Comment: This does seem rather unlikely, given the number of times Thanos has been too dead to keep a constant watch on anyone.